# How to add some content in menu item admin panel Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-1.4

I have create some menu and his sub menu in admin panel(it displays me a blank page) so i want to add some input then this input I want to do some SQL query (Save text in db), and this text i want to display it in some sms page. I dont know how.

[Menu admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRIrT.jpg)

W/Testimony/controllers/Adminhtml/TestimonyController.php

```
class W_Testimony_Adminhtml_TestimonyController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{


protected function _initAction() {
    $this->_title($this->__('Paramétrage'))
        ->_title($this->__('Témoignage'));
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('testimony/parametrage')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('testimony'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('testimony'))
        ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Paramétrage'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Paramétrage'));
    return $this;
}

public function indexAction() {
    $this->_initAction()
        ->renderLayout();
}
}
```

W/Testimony/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
<menu>
    <testimony translate="title" module="testimony">
                <title>Témoignage</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <parametrage translate="title" module="testimony">
                    <title>Paramétrage</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/testimony/index</action>
                    </parametrage>
                </children>
    </testimony>
</menu>
```

W/Testimony/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <W_Testimony>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </W_Testimony>
</modules>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <testimony>
                <file>testimony.xml</file> <!-- I dont know what is this file ?-->
            </testimony>
        </updates>
    </layout>

    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <testimony>
                        <title>testimony Menu Item</title>
                        <children>
                            <parametrage translate="title" module="testimony">
                                <title>param Menu Item</title>
                            </parametrage>
                        </children>
                    </testimony>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
<global>
<models>
        <w_testimony>
            <class>W_Testimony_Model</class>
        </w_testimony>
    </models>

    <helpers>
        <testimony>
            <class>W_Testimony_Helper</class>
        </testimony>
    </helpers>

    <blocks>
        <w_testimony>
            <class>W_Testimony_Block</class>
        </w_testimony>

        <w_testimony_adminhtml>
            <class>W_Testimony_Block_Adminhtml</class>
        </w_testimony_adminhtml>
    </blocks>

</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <w_testimony after="Mage_Adminhtml">W_Testimony_Adminhtml</w_testimony>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

W/Testimony/Helper/Data.php

```
class W_Testimony_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

}
```

W/Testimony/Model/Testimony.php

```
class W_Testimony_Model_Testimony extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{


public function _construct() {
    $this->_isPkAutoIncrement = false;
    $this->_init('w_testimony/testimony');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this instruction and create page in admin.

[Create Module](https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Create+a+custom+module+with+a+custom+database+table)